# I still get You are seeing this page because DEBUG=True is in your settings file and you have not configured any URLs

Tags: python, django

1. thats my app urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.tasklist, name='tasks'),
]
```

2. thats my projects urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('list.urls')),
]
```

3. thats views urls

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def tasklist(request):
  return HttpResponse('TO DO List')
```

I tried a lot of things but none of them worked

Answer (score 1):

you have to add your app into INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py